# Sequentially update a column with a decrementing value

Tags: plsql

I need a script that will update the "QTY_REQ" column in the PLSQL table in the screen cap below sequentially row by row by dividing out a number (e.g. 7) among the rows.
I want to start with the row with the highest value in QTY (QTY 4, LOC 10800B41) and enter 4 for QTY_REQ.
Then go to the second row (QTY 2, LOC 10800A01) and enter 2 for QTY_REQ.
Then finally go to the third row (QTY 2, LOC 10800B01) and enter 1 for QTY_REQ.
So I evenly divide out the values and stop when the total is reached. The number could be 5 and would just fill in the first two rows (4 entered for for QTY_REQ for the first and 1 entered for for QTY_REQ for the second)
Important point; the value that is entered for QTY_REQ cannot be higher than the value that is in the QTY column for that row.
If someone can help with this that would be appreciated, thank you.

https://ibb.co/nw2F83R

The script that creates the table can be downloaded here https://file.io/fryZeKgxFMZG

[image]

Comment: I think you need to look at the `RANK` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone on another forum gave me this solution (which seems to work)

create or replace PROCEDURE  set_qty_req (v_distribute_in IN FLOAT,pick_key IN VARCHAR2,p_no IN VARCHAR2) as

BEGIN
declare

v_distribute  FLOAT := v_distribute_in;
BEGIN
FOR i IN
(SELECT ROWID AS rid, qty
FROM   MATLIST2
WHERE  qty_req IS NULL AND PICK_KEY =pick_key AND PART_=p_no
ORDER  BY qty DESC, ROWID)
LOOP
IF v_distribute >= i.qty THEN
UPDATE MATLIST2
SET    qty_req = i.qty
WHERE  ROWID = i.rid AND   PICK_KEY =pick_key AND PART_=p_no;
commit;
v_distribute := v_distribute - i.qty;
commit;
ELSIF v_distribute < i.qty THEN
UPDATE MATLIST2
SET    qty_req = v_distribute
WHERE  ROWID = i.rid AND PICK_KEY =pick_key AND PART_=p_no;
v_distribute := v_distribute - v_distribute;
commit;
END IF;
IF v_distribute = 0 THEN EXIT;
END IF;
END LOOP;
END;

END;

Answer (score 1):

You can use SQL or PL/SQL. There are various techniques for doing it in SQL, most requiring a windowing function to aggregate across rows. Here's one:

```
MERGE INTO matlist2 tgt
USING (SELECT loc,
              qty,
              LEAST(qty,GREATEST(0,assignment_amt - NVL(last_running_qty,0))) qty_req
         FROM (SELECT loc,
                      qty,
                      SUM(qty) OVER (ORDER BY qty DESC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) last_running_qty,
                      7 assignment_amt
                 FROM matlist2)) src
  ON (src.loc = tgt.loc)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE tgt.qty_req = src.qty_req
```

A more straight-forward approach that is easier to read would be a simple PL/SQL script that simply uses a variable to keep track of what remains of the assignment value:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_assign_qty (in_assignment_amount IN integer := 0)
AS
  var_remainder integer := in_assignment_amount;
BEGIN
  FOR rec_assign IN (SELECT * FROM matlist2 ORDER BY qty DESC)
  LOOP
    EXIT WHEN var_remainder <= 0;
    
    UPDATE matlist2 
       SET qty_req = LEAST(var_remainder,qty)
     WHERE loc = rec_assign.loc;
     
    var_remainder := var_remainder - LEAST(var_remainder,qty);
  END LOOP;
END;
/

BEGIN f_assign_qty(7); END;
/
```